# How to check EACH of numerous web-socket connections created in Jmeter get ALL updates from server

Tags: performance, websocket, jmeter, live-streaming

There is a live-streaming service where comments could be added just like it is happening on YouTube.
My goal is to check performance on client side.

Through jmeter I created N websocket connections.
The problem is to check that all connections receive correct information.

For one connection, you can view the responses from the server with your eyes and check that the updates come in synchronously with how comments are added.
But if there are 500 connections, then you can’t see it with your eyes.
And if every connection updates fly every 200 ms, then even more so.

**The question is **: how to check that EVERY connection created has received ALL updates from the server.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides mechanism to apply pass/fail criteria to its Samplers via [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions).

The most popular is [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) you can check whether Sampler's response contains the data you expect it to contain or vice versa.

Check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-assertions) article for more information on JMeter Assertions concept.